# Interpolation along one dimension of a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate an `M*N` matrix. For example, matrix `T` represents Temperature and matrix `B` represents the location:

```
T = [1 3 5; ...
     2 4 6; ...
     1 2 3];
B = [0.1 0.2 0.3; ...
     0.1 0.2 0.3; ...
     0.1 0.2 0.3];
```

I am trying to get the Temperature information at locations `0.15` and `0.25`. So, matrix `B` will be like:

```
New_B = [0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3; ...
         0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3; ...
         0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3];
```

and the expected results for matrix `T` will be:

```
T = [1 2 3 4 5; ...
     2 3 4 5 6; ...
     1 1.5 2 2.5 3];
```

I tried:

```
New_T = interp2(T, B, New_B);
```

But it does not work. How can I do this interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to a matrix, in which case it will operate along each column. Since you want to interpolate along each row, you will have to [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) your inputs and your outputs. You also only need one row each of `B` and `New_B`:

```
New_T = interp1(B(1, :).', T.', New_B(1, :).').';

New_T =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000
```

In case you were curious, you would have to specify additional row grid points to use [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html):

```
New_T = interp2(B(1, :), (1:size(B, 1)).', T, New_B(1, :), (1:size(New_B, 1)).');
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a for-loop because interp1 only works for a single row.

```
T=[ 1 3 5; 2 4 6; 1 2 3];
B=[0.1 0.2 0.3; 0.1 0.2 0.3; 0.1 0.2 0.3];


B_new = [0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3; 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3; 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3];

T_new = cell(2,1);

for k=1:size(B,1)

    T_new{k} =  interp1(B(1,:),T(k,:),B_new(k,:)); 

end

T_new = cell2mat(T_new)
```

**Output:**

```
T_new =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000
```

Comment: Thank you. can I use interp2? because I have a large data and Loop will kill the program.

Comment: interp2 assumes a relation between the values in the 2nd dimension as well. You can make the loop fast by predeclaring a matrix instead of a cell. `T_new = nan(size(B_new))` and `T_new(k,:) = interp1(...` interp1 is very fast.  I cannot imagine how it would kill the program.